# How to show that $w_n=S_n/S_{n-1}$ solves $w_n=1+1/w_{n-1}$ if $S_{n+1}=S_n+S_{n-1}$

Tags: real-analysis

Let a sequence be given by $S_{n+1}=S_n+S_{n-1}$ where $S_1=1$ and $S_2=2$.

Let $w_n= \frac{S_n}{S_{n-1}}$ for all $n \geq 2$.

How would I show that $w_n=1+ \frac{1}{w_{n-1}}$ for all $n \geq 2$? I know if I solved $w_n= \frac{S_n}{S_{n-1}}$  for some of the n's I would see that $w_n=1+ \frac{1}{w_{n-1}}$, but I don't understand how I would show this.

Comment: hint: expand $S_n = S_{n-1} + S_{n-2}$ in the numerator of $w_n$

Answer (score 1):

Note
$$ w_n= \frac{S_n}{S_{n-1}}=\frac{S_{n-1}+S_{n-2}}{S_{n-1}}=1+\frac{1}{\frac{S_{n-1}}{S_{n-2}}}=1+\frac1{w_{n-1}}. $$

Comment: That makes so much sense, thanks. I'm probably just overthinking the problem, but is there anything else that I need to show? It seems almost to simple if that's all I need to do.

Comment: I doubt there is.